# Can't access web, only server default page is showing

Tags: web-hosting, server, vps, plesk, multiple-domains

I have just moved to a VPS server. I have uploaded my files to httpdcos/ but then when I access my website, it still shows the server default page.

How do I fix this?
My website is at 216.87.168.104 - the server runs Parallels Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because apache doesn't serves your website on IP to which your domain name resolved.

1. Check IP of your domain:

   `nslookup <yourdomain.tld>`
2. Check output of `apachectl -S` - make sure that domain name is served on resolved IP address